# Integrate $\sin(3x)\cos(3x)$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Integrate $\sin(3x)\cos(3x)$

I looked at various answers on different sites but still do not understand how to use the u-substitution method in this question or the double angle rule.

Comment: $\sin3x\cos3x=\frac{1}{2}\sin6x$.

Comment: $\sin3x \cos 3x\ dx = \frac13 \sin3x \ d(\sin 3x)$

Answer (score 5):

$\int\sin3x\cos3x \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}=\int\frac{1}{2}\sin6x \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}=-\frac{1}{12}\cos6x+C$

Comment: @IrregularUser Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Just a slightly nicer looking differential :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this :
\begin{align*}\int \sin(3x)\cos(3x)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x} & = \frac{1}{3}\int 3\sin(3x)\cos(3x)\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}
\\ & = \frac{1}{3} \int \sin(3x)(\sin(3x))' \mathop{\mathrm{d}x}
\\ & = \frac{1}{6} \int (\sin(3x)^2)'\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}
\\ & = \frac{1}{6}\sin(3x)^2 +K\end{align*}

This is in fact the same as doing a substitution $u=\sin(3x)$.

Note also that though it may seem different than almagest's solution, the two are equivalent. Indeed,
$$\cos(6x)^2=1-2\sin(3x)^2,$$
so that
$$-\frac{1}{12}\cos(6x)+C=-\frac{1}{12}(1-2\sin(3x)^2)+C=\frac{1}{6}\sin(3x)^2+C-\frac{1}{12},$$
which is the same as my answer if you choose $K=C-\frac{1}{12}$.